# Select div class given attribute = variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, attributes, jquery-selectors

```
var i = $( ".map_tile:contains('X')" ).attr('index');
$( ".map_tile[index*=i]" ).text('');
```

the console logs i as 2225 which is correct, but when I attempt to access

```
<div class='map_tile' index='2225'>X</div>
```

Any pointers in whats going wrong here?

Comment: A variable can't be evaluated when it's part of a `string`. You need to use concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to find element with `index`, that contains string **i**. Use concatenation with `i` value instead:

```
$( ".map_tile[index*=" + i + "]" ).text('');
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/49hqe76u/).

Answer (score 2):

You problem is the `i` value, it  does not recognized inside the string becouse It's a var and can't be avaluated:

```
$( ".map_tile[index*="+ i +"]" ).text('');
```